# sap.m.input focus doesn't work the second time in Fiori Launchpad

Tags: input, focus, sapui5, sap-fiori, setfocus

I am trying to set focus on the first field of the SAPUI5 application; it works well for the first time using `focus()`.

But when we come out of the app and launch the app again from the Fiori Launchpad, the first field doesn't get focused. Rather the app header on Fiori Launchpad gets highlighted with dashed borders.

Is there a way to implement consistent focus on the `sap.m.input` field? Any inputs?

Comment: The issue with FLP taking the control of the initial focus was a bug which is no longer reproducible since SAPUI5 1.104.0

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using var Input = this.getView().byId("idOrderNumberInput"); jQuery.sap.delayedCall(500, this, function () { Input.focus(); });